# Wikipedia People API

Tags: dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I want to use wikipedia API to list the peoples whose birthday is on particular date.

Anybody has used it before? Please advice me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia doesn't provide this information directly, try [DBPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads37#persondata).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia hosts its data on Wikidata, which is powered by the [Wikibase web API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API).